# How to store numpy.ndarray in the columns of DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

In Structured Streaming how can I create two new columns using UDF that returns `numpy.ndarray` with two elements?

This is what I have until now:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("host_id", LongType()),
    StructField("fence_id", LongType()),
    StructField("policy_id", LongType()),
    StructField("timestamp", LongType()),
    StructField("distances", ArrayType(LongType()))
])

ds = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("json") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .load("data/")

ds.printSchema()
pa = PosAlgorithm()
get_distance_udf = udf(lambda y: pa.getLocation(y), ArrayType(LongType()))
dfnew = ds.withColumn("location", get_distance_udf(col("distances")))

query = dfnew \
    .writeStream \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

The function `pa.getLocation` returns `numpy.ndarray`, e.g. `[42.15999863,  2.08498164]`. I want to store these numbers in two new columns of the DataFrame `dfnew` called as `latitude` and `longitude`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
get_distance_udf = udf(lambda y: pa.getLocation(y), ArrayType(LongType()))
```

with

```
get_distance_udf = udf(
     lambda y: pa.getLocation(y).tolist(), 
     StructType([
         StructField("latitude", DoubleType()), 
         StructField("longitude", DoubleType())
     ])
)
```

and expand the result afterwards, if needed:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

(ds
    .withColumn("location", get_distance_udf(col("distances")))
    .withColumn("latitude", col("location.latitude"))
    .withColumn("longitude", col("location.longitude")))
```